# reverse call in C++ template function

Tags: c++, templates

I can't make a reverse call inside a template function,though the parameters passed to it seems no problem.
First is the header file:

```
#ifndef TestTemplate_TestTemplate_h
#define TestTemplate_TestTemplate_h

template<int size>
void printArray(int (*iarr)[size]);

#include "TestTemplate.cpp"
#endif
```

second is the .cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
template<int size>
void printArray(int (*iarr)[size]){
    if(size == 1){
        return;
    }
    else{
        const int s = size - 1;
        cout << size << endl;
        int arr[s][s] = {};
        printArray<s>(arr);
    }
}
```

Last is the main file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "TestTemplate.h"
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    const int size = 4;
    int iarr[size][size]= {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4}};
    printArray<size>(iarr);
}
```

now I got a compilation error saying that

```
no matching function for call to 'printArray'
```

in the source file.
Maybe there's some grammars in template programming I don't know here.Wish somebody can point it to me.Thanks very much.

Comment: Where is `TestTemplate.h` included, offhand ?

Comment: How do you call `printArray`? It should be specialized: `printArray<size>(arr)`, including the invocation from withing the function itself.

Comment: @Stan:I did as you said.But still got that error.

Comment: @WhozCraig:I have included source file into header file.You can see it.

Comment: @tuanlong, please, show how you call the function in main?

Comment: @tuanlong, also why do you have different function prototypes in declaration and definition (`arr[]` and `*arr`)? should be the same.

Comment: @Stan:I have added the main file codes to this question.

Comment: @Stan:I have unified the declaration and definition.

Comment: This may shed a little light on the ultimate problem, my Apple LLVM 4.1 compiler emits this as the ultimate root cause (see AndreyT's answer for why): `main.cpp:17:28: Candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with size = 0]`

Answer (score 4):

You cannot terminate template recursion (which is generated entirely at compile time) by using run-time constructs like `if`. The compiler always has to instantiate both branches of your `if` inside `printArray`, even if it "knows" that one of the branches will not be executed. This means that your compile-time recursion is not really terminated. It is potentially infinite. It just bottoms out with a compilation error when the compiler attempts to declare an array `arr` of size `0`, which is illegal. This is what triggers the error.

Again, when the compiler generates `printArray<1>`, it instantiates the code for both branches of the inner `if`, meaning that it will attempt to declare

```
int arr[0][0] = {};
```

which is illegal.

The error message you are getting from your compiler is misleading, probably because your compiler implements some non-standard extensions allowing it to accept zero-sized arrays. In reality the error should be triggered by the zero-sized array declaration.

If you are trying to implement compile-time template recursion, you have to use compile-time techniques (as opposed to run-time branching) to make it bottom out. In your case it can be done by using explicit specialization, i.e. by adding a separate explicitly specialized non-recursive version of `printArray` for arrays of size `1`.

```
template<>
void printArray<1>(int (*iarr)[1]) {
}
```

(I don't know why you are not doing anything for arrays of size `1`, I just faithfully reproduced your intended functionality.)

Alternatively, you can achieve the same effect by using ordinary function overloading instead of explicit template specialization. Declare this overloaded version

```
void printArray(int (*iarr)[1]) {
}
```

and it will solve the problem as well. (Just remember that in this case it has to be declared *before* the recursive `printArray` template).

Of course, now you no longer need branching inside your recursive version

```
template<int size>
void printArray(int (*iarr)[size]) {
    const int s = size - 1;
    cout << size << endl;
    int arr[s][s] = {};
    printArray<s>(arr);
}
```

P.S. And there's no need to specify the template argument of `printArray` explicitly in your code sample. You can just call your function as `printArray(arr)`. The compiler will deduce the `size`.

Comment: Thank you very much.I have learned a lot from what you said.I'll try again.